# Stacked bar plot from 3-dimension data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, bar-chart

My dataframe (loaded from .csv file) looks like this:

[image]

I want to make a graph that looks like this (done in excel):

[image]

I've tried this:

```
barplot(t(as.matrix(df)), beside = FALSE, names.arg = df$cause, legend.text = TRUE, ylab = "Average Length (days)", xlab = "Cause")
```

It didn't work, and gave me this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reshaping the data to long. Here the code for a solution using `ggplot2` and `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Data
df <- data.frame(Cause=c('Cellulitis','Convulsions and epilepsy',
                         'Dental conditions','Ear, nose and throat infections'),
                 under=c(3.7,2,1.2,1.2),
                 over=c(5.4,3.9,1.8,2.5),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Plot
df %>% pivot_longer(-Cause) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Cause,y=value,fill=name))+
  geom_col(color='black')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'top')+
  scale_fill_manual('',values=c('tomato','cornflowerblue'))
```

Output:

[image]

And for further customization you can use this:

```
#Plot 2
df %>% pivot_longer(-Cause) %>%
  mutate(name=paste(name,'65')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Cause,y=value,fill=name))+
  geom_col(color='black')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'top')+
  scale_fill_manual('',values=c('tomato','cornflowerblue'))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, when I try run the plot code I get this error: "Error: `cols` must select at least one column.". I'm new to R so not sure what's causing this.

Comment: @Sam It must be in the `pivot_longer()` could you please share the `str(yourdataframe)` in order to see the names of your variables also try loading the packages I mention at the start of the question. Let me know how that goes!

Comment: hmm when I do that i get `'data.frame': 0 obs. of  0 variables`. Must be something wrong with my frame, right?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like no data is present. Try checking the structure of data and see if it is the same as the data I shared which is a clon of your screenshot. Let me know how that goes or invite me to chat I am glad to help https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187426/how-do-i-chat-with-another-user-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Ah nevermind, I got it working, there was an unrelated error somewhere else. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Using the reshape2 package and ggplot2 you can transform the data into longer format then use the type i.e `over|under` as a fill.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
ggplot(data=melt(dt,id.vars="cause"),aes(x=cause, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

## Result

[image]

## data

```
dt <- read.csv(text="cause,under,over
Cellulitis,3.7,5.4
Convulsions and epilepsy,2,3.9
Dental conditions,1.2,1.8
Ear; nose and throat infections,1.2,2.5")
```